# When scp a folder from an android phone to Ubuntu: `not a regular file` error

Tags: ssh, android

I run "[SSH Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.sshserver&hl=en)" in my android phone, to set up a SSH server.

Then in my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop, I try to copy a folder `paper` from my phone:

```
$ scp -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -P 49882 e@192.168.1.2:/sdcard/Download/paper .
e@192.168.1.2's password: 
com.icecoldapps.sshserver.a.h@41cf0550 not a regular file
```

What does the `not a regular file` error mean and what shall I do to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Not a regular file means its not a regular file; ie. it could be directory, a hard-link, a soft-link, a block-device,  a char-device, link (hard, soft).....  eg. a `stat /dev/fuse` will report its a character-special-file.

Comment: what shall I do to solve the problem?

Comment: how to resolve depends upon what type of `file` it is.  eg. a `file /dev` tells me its a directory so I'd scp the dev/* or just scp -r /dev so it copies directory and contents.  (my using /dev is only an example - it's a directory that I know contains lots of file types)  if it's a special file the reason or type will dictate (some can't be scp'd; eg. a event-device such as a keyboard you can't expect to scp/cp).